# C++17 copy elision and object destruction

Tags: c++, c++17, copy-elision, object-destruction

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision),

> When copy elision occurs, the implementation treats the source and
>   target of the omitted copy/move (since C++11) operation as simply two
>   different ways of referring to the same object, and the destruction of
>   that object occurs at the later of the times when the two objects
>   would have been destroyed without the optimization (except that, if
>   the parameter of the selected constructor is an rvalue reference to
>   object type, the destruction occurs when the target would have been
>   destroyed) (since C++17).

For a simple case like `A a = returnA();`, I can understand that the object is not destroyed in `returnA()` and instead the destruction occurs as in the case `A a;` which is the later time.

I can't think of a case which the opposite happens such that the source of the copy/move operation is destroyed first. Also I would like an example of the added statement since C++17 (exception when parameter of selected constructor is an rvalue reference to object type)

Comment: So... what exactly is your question here?

Comment: There are two questions: in which case the object created in `returnA` could outlive the `a` it is "created" into? and the second question is: what does mean the provision added in C++17: `(except that, if the parameter of the selected constructor is an rvalue reference to object type, the destruction occurs when the target would have been destroyed)`

Comment: "*in which case the object created in returnA could outlive the a it is "created" into?*" I'm not sure I understand the question. The quoted paragraph doesn't say that there are such cases.

Comment: Could help : https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/value_category

Comment: Do you mean "source" or "target"?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas "in which case the object created in returnA could outlive the a it is "created" into?" My first question is exactly this

Comment: @T.C. Doesn't "source" mean the object that would have been created in `returnA` without copy elision and "target" means the `a` in `A a = returnA();`?

Comment: @Nicol Bolas The paragraph doesn't say there can be cases where the object created in `returnA` could outlive the `a`it is "created" into. But why does it say "destruction of that object occurs at the **later of the times when the two** objects would have been destroyed without the optimization"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The symmetric case where the source outlives the target is when the prvalue is a parameter:

```
struct A {
  static int *data;
  A() {if(!refs++) data=new int(42);}
  A(const A&) {++refs;}  // not movable
  ~A() {if(!--refs) delete data;}
private:
  static int refs;
};
int A::refs,*A::data;
int* f(A) {return A::data;}
A returnA();
int returnInt() {return *f(returnA());} // ok
```

Because the result of `returnA()` is a temporary, its lifetime extends to the end of the `return` statement’s *full-expression*.  The implementation may identify it with `f`’s parameter, but may not destroy it when `f` returns, so the dereference in `returnInt` is valid.  (Note that parameters [*may* survive that long](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.call#7) anyway.)

The adjustment in C++17 (along with such elision being guaranteed) is that if you (would) *move* the prvalue, it may be destroyed when the parameter is (since you shouldn’t be relying on its contents anyway).  If that’s when `f` returns, the (ill-advised) code above becomes invalid if `A` is made movable.

Comment: I swapped the copy constructor with a move constructor, and changed the `returnInt` to `int returnInt() {return *f(move(returnA()));}`. That results in a call sequence `A(), A(const A&&), ~A(), ~A()`. Is that what the C++17 adjustment is about?

Comment: That merely demonstrates that calling `move` on a prvalue forces a temporary to be materialized.  (In C++14 terms, it prevents the optional copy/move elision.)

Comment: But when I swapped the copy constructor with a move constructor only (and added visible printf side effect in it), I don't see that the move constructor gets called either (with gcc-8). What do you mean by "the (ill-advised) code above becomes invalid if A is made movable"?

Comment: @pterodragon: The move constructor isn’t called, but its *selection* **allows** the argument/parameter to be destroyed (destroying `data`) before `data` is dereferenced.

Comment: I presume the definition of `returnA()` is `A returnA() { {}; }`?

Comment: @JonHarper: Does its body matter?  The argument depends only on there being no *other* `A` objects (and that only because of the `static` variables used as an example).

Comment: Not particularly. Just being thorough that I understood your answer.